# I'm getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'" error when installing fbprophet or pystan via pip

Tags: python, cython, facebook-prophet, pystan

so i have been working on a python project and needed the fbprophet library. aditionally i wanted to install pystan to run it more smootly. Anyhow, whenever i do tho' i get the same error message

```
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-q5vdkmd7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-q5vdkmd7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-q5vdkmd7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-q5vdkmd7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 122, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

i have been trying using pip to install it just like everything else.
i am just learning how to code so i dont understand what any of this means.

i have been trying to paste the error message into google and test the various solutions but neither installing it again, updating it, installing it directly where the scripts are worked. honestly i dont remember everything i tried but those are about the solutions the internet had provided.
i have no idea if it is of any use but im using:
python 3.12.2
pip 24.0
cython 3.0.9

Comment: "i have no idea if it is of any use but im using: python 3.12.2 pip 24.0 cython 3.0.9" - **how do you know** that you have this version of Cython available? What happens if you try opening the Python interpreter prompt (make sure you are using the **same installation of Python** that Pip is using, and make sure you understand how to do that), and try `import Cython`?